# What is a common name for a user that is not an end-user?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

I'm struggling to come up with some proper naming schemes. We build a service that is offered to end-users through our own app, which is what we have done from day one. The users, AKA people who download our app and use it, we've always just called 'users', which was just fine.

Recently we have started growing our product into a 'service-as-a-service' kind of thing, where our service is indirectly offered to users of other companies (though their own apps/websites/whatever) by offering our service to those parties through an API/SDK. Sort of like what companies such as Intercom and Appsflyer. In this new scenario we suddenly have (at least) 3 kinds of users, namely:

1. The users of our own app, that we always had
2. the end-user we already had, except they're now using our product through a 3rd-party interface. These are basically the same as user (1), except for some differences in accounting/attribution/etc
3. the company/enthousiast/... that is the supplier of the product through which user (2) uses our facilities that mainly performs management tasks, but also has access to all functionality available to user (1) and (2).

We started out calling user (3) 'partners', since this service was initially only available to selected parties we had strong bonds with. However now that we're moving to making these services available to basically anyone (including paid- and non-paid plans), 'partner' doesn't seem right anymore.

This is now starting to cause unclarity that can be noticed both in inconsistent naming in code and data models, as well as confusing communication in meetings.

So, my question is, what are common ways to distinctively name these different types of users? Also, is there a common way to refer to what I now called 'Service-as-a-Service'? As this would become ambiguous with SaaS ('Software as a Service'), which is a quite different concept.

Answer (score 1):

partner is not a bad approach, I've used channel (a bit un-personal) and eco-system in the past. Basically they serve to add value to our value by being part of our eco-system